How to Update Prisma Types Dynamically Without Deleting Data in Postgres Database in a Nest.js Backend?
I have a Nest.js backend deployed on an EC2 instance, which is connected to a Postgres database on a separate server. The backend has some basic API endpoints, and I’m using the types provided by the Prisma client in my controllers and services for the parameter types.
Here’s an example of how I’m using Prisma types:
 @Post() create(@Body() createUserDto: Prisma.usersCreateInput) { return this.usersService.create(createUserDto); }
The database structure is not yet finalized, and new columns are being added to tables almost daily. The Prisma types are updated after running Prisma generate, which is causing a problem because it deletes all the data in the database.
Is there a way to dynamically update the Prisma types as the table structure changes without deleting the existing data in the database?

Regenerating Prisma types most certainly does not erase any data. You are doing something very wrong. What you should be doing is changing the Prisma schema, creating a migration for the changes, and running it locally to ensure the end result is what you desire. Once the migration file is merged to your codebase, you should run it against production DB. Study Prisma's documentation on migrations to do it properly: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-migrate/getting-started

Generating Prisma types does not erase any data, as mentioned by Prettu in the comment. In fact, this process does not affect the data in any way. What does effect data are migrations. So if you want just the types, all you have to do is change the Prisma schema, and run npx prisma generate. This will create the Prisma Client with all the types inferred from your schema file.
But keep in mind that until you create and apply migrations, your database is no longer in sync with your local schema. If you added a new column or a new table, your database does not know of that. So queries, and mutations will fail.
Hope that clears some of your confusion.
